# Put the bedsheet on the wrong way(the wrong side up)

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

A bedsheet/sheet with patterns put on the bed,and the pattern is inverted(someone put it on the bed the wrong way)

So what would you use to describe that?Is there an expression to express that?

[image]

(This one's put on the right way,but what if the flowers were facing the other side (that's not the way they are meant to be))

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Are you suggesting the pillow and/or duvet covers might have been put on ***inside out**?* If not, I have no concept of what "wrong way" might mean as regards the "orientation" of floral designs on bedding.

Comment: No the duvet cover haven't been put on inside out. It's actually the direction of "flower" pattern that is not the way it should be. Yes you can say wrong "orientation". So what would you use for the  right direction of flowers? @FumbleFingers

Comment: When someone asks for clarification, please use the [edit] button to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

If your expectation is that the stems are pointing toward the foot of the bed and the flowers are toward the head of the bed, but instead the reverse is true, then you can say that the sheets are **"upside down".**

If your expectation is that the side of the sheet with the flowers visible is facing outward (away from the mattress) and the side with the seams is inward, but the reverse is true, then you can say that the sheets are "**inside out"**.

Comment: If the blanket had the cover on it rightside-out (i.e. the correct way) but the pattern was only on the top side, and then someone flipped the blanket over so that only the un-patterned side of the cover were visible (facing up) and the patterned side faced the mattress, I think that would also qualify as “upside down”. This is my understanding of the problem the OP describes, but it is not 100% clear.

Comment: No @Mixolydian , that's not what I meant. It's like the flowers are inverted or face toward the pillows while they have to point toward the foot of the bed. "It's not upside-down" that is,the colrful side is not  facing down

Comment: Ok then it’s what @Hellion said and this would also be “upside down” where “down” is the foot of the bed, not the flipside of the duvet. But since there are at least two interpretations of “upside down”, you might need to be more descriptive and say something like “upside down with respect to the head of the bed” - it’s hard since “top”/“up” could mean either the head of the bed (pillow end) or the side of the duvet facing away from the mattress.